# css styling based on text value of a list item

Tags: css, list, icons

I am using markdown to generate documentation, and I'd like to be able to use custom images for list items based on the text value of that list item. I don't have any control over the generated html, so the css needs to be driven by the text value. For example:

```
<ul>
<li>/myFolder</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to use an image of a folder if the text begins with a slash.
I was hoping something like this would work:

```
li[li^='/']
{
list-style-image:url(images/folder.png); 
}
```

But, no luck.

Comment: You can't do that with just CSS.

Comment: impossible. write  perhaps some attribute like: `data-text="/myfolder"` to be able to access it - or just use a class.

Comment: What prevents you from having control over the generated HTML?

Comment: The markdown spec only allows for some thing like this: - /myfolder, which generates <ul><li>/myFolder</li></ul>. The html is generated using a perl script against the markdown text.

Comment: If you know what the order of the generated items is, you can use things like `nth-child`. But the best way, of course, it to try and get control over the HTML that is generated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the desired result using a pseudo link.

Here is the css:

```
a:link[href^='#folder']
{
    margin-top: 4px;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:18px;
    padding-left:20px;
    background:transparent url(images/folder.png) center left no-repeat;
}
a:link[href^='#folder2']
{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

a:link[href^='#folder3']
{
    margin-left: 40px;
}

a:link[href^='#folder4']
{
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

This allows me to create a nested folder structure by specifying the depth in the href. The result is this:
[image]